# HighCharts change default x-values spacing to 0.5

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a series of values by 0.5 minute:

```
[
    0, 0.004, 0.008, 0.013, 0.017, 0.021, 0.025, 0.029, 0.033, 0.037,
    0.042, 0.046, 0.05, 0.054, 0.058, 0.062, 0.067, 0.071, 0.075, 0.079, 0.083
]
```

something like that.

When I don't specify categories for the x axis, it places my numbers at `0, 1, 2...`, but I want them at `0, 0.5, 1, 1.5...`

Is there a way in the Highcharts config to specify the default spacing?

I want to avoid generating a categories list, and I cannot use the `{x: 0.5, y: 0.004}` syntax, because the json would be too big (I'm generating data for like 3000 entries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval) as 0.5 on series options.

Comment: No, that puts ticks at 0, 0.5, 1..., but my points will be at 0, 1, 2

Comment: set pointInterval: 0.5, http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval

Comment: That's it, please add it to the answer, so I can accept it. Can't accept a comment.